# Queue Linked list dequeue function

Tags: c++, linked-list, queue

I am currently learning about various linked lists queues and stacks. I have being reading some notes on various queue functions. I am having trouble understanding the provided dequeue function.

```
void CintQueue::Dequeue(int& item) //Remove front Item from the Queue
{
   Node *TempPtr;

   TempPtr = m_qFront;
   item = m_qFront->data;
   m_qFront = m_qFront->next;
   if (m_qFront == NULL)
       m_qRear = NULL;
   delete TempPtr;
}
```

I'm don't understand why there is a parameter being passed to dequeue. What is it's purpose? I see from the code that it is being assigned the data value from the front node but the function dequeue has no return value so I don't understand it's purpose. Could someone please explain how this function works?
Would a separate function be required to obtain the value that is removed from the queue?

Comment: Looks more like a `pop_front` where you remove the element at the head and then return it, only here instead of returning it, you take an output parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function argument is passed a reference.  So when it gets set in the function, it sets the variable that was passed as the argument:

```
CintQueue q;  // define queue
// fill q with ints
int i;
q.Dequeue(i);  // i is set here
```

Comment: Thank you very much, helped me understand much clearer than the notes I've read

Comment: If this answers your question, please accept it.  Also, take a look here for a good reference to the C++ standard library, including std::queue: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue

Answer (score 0):

You pass a reference of a variable of the same type that the first object of the queue has. In the method the data of the first item is saved into this variable and then the item gets deleted. So you can get the data of queues head item and delete it with just one function call.

Passing a reference to a function and assigning something to it is a way for void functions to return something. You could also make a method with the same purpose with a return value and without an argument.